# Indignado con/por/de

Tags: preposiciones, adjetivos

¿Cuáles de la siguientes oraciones son correctas? Todas tienen que ver con la palabra que sigue a *indignado*. ¿Cuáles son las permitidas?

1. Estoy indignado **con que** haya cenizas ahí.
2. Estoy indignado **conque** haya cenizas ahí.
3. Estoy indignado **de que** haya cenizas ahí.
4. Estoy indignado **por que** hay cenizas ahí.
5. Estoy indignado **porque** hay cenizas ahí.

¿Se ve alguna diferencia en el significado de cada oración?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La 1, 3 y 5 son correctas. La 5 me suena más natural. Las otras dos no son correctas:

- 2: la palabra *conque* tiene un sentido similar a *así que*, por lo que no corresponde en este caso.
- 4: para introducir una causa se usa la conjunción *porque*. Ver [esta consulta](http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que) en el sitio de la RAE.

Otra forma de expresar lo mismo sería:

> Me indigna que haya cenizas ahí.

Comment: De acuerdo en todo, exceptuando una cosa. _Conque_ es una conjunción, no muy utilizada quizás.

Comment: @David se usa tan poco que me olvidé de su existencia. Arreglado.

Comment: Según el DPD, *de* se puede utilizar. *con* y *contra* indican el destinatario de la indignación y *por* y *de* indican la causa de ella.

Comment: @David Yo la uso sin parar. Tal vez dependa de las zonas.

Comment: @guifa edité mi respuesta para incluirla. Encontré suficientes ejemplos en internet como para convencerme de que se usa, si bien a mí no me suena para nada.

Comment: @Gorpik ¿Seguro? ¿qué tan fácil se distingue _conque_ de _con que_ al hablar? Incluso puede merecer otra pregunta en otro hilo: ¿Cuál se utiliza más en tal país?

Comment: @David Claro que seguro. Sé qué palabras uso y cuáles no :) Esa la utilizo mucho; probablemente sea usual en Aragón, de donde soy, y no en otros sitios.